# How prove this inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1-2\sin{\frac{C}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{B}{2}}}\ge 0$

Tags: inequality

in $\Delta ABC$,prove or disprove 
$$\dfrac{1-2\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}}{\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}}+\dfrac{1-2\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}}{\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}}+\dfrac{1-2\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}}{\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}}\ge 0$$

My idea: since
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{1-2\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}}{\sin{\dfrac{B}{2}}}\ge 0$$
$$\sum_{cyc}\sin{\dfrac{A}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}}(1-2\sin{\dfrac{C}{2}})\ge 0$$
then I can't

Thank you for you help

Comment: Should not the combination be cyclic  like th last term will be $$\frac{1-2\sin\frac B2}{\sin\frac A2}$$